# Risks of using an Activity as a supplier of API

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating an application for Android which I want to turn into a library module and use its own logic as a common logic for several other application which differs in their UI. The library module got an Android service which can receive and send commands to a listener which is defined in the application itself (in my case in the main activity).

On the receiving side, The listener is the main activity of the application which then invokes callbacks according to the type of message from the service.

The issue is more with the sending commands to the service part. The API in question is the way of the application to send messages to the service. It simply gets the argument of the message to send and pass it along to the service.

The way I thought of doing it is making the library's main activity as the API which will allow both the sending and receiving events. The developer of a UI using this library will then simply need to make another module for the GUI alone, and make his main activity extend the library's main activity, thus being able to use the API and extend the listener's behavior.

What I want to know is possible technical issues, and not an opinion if the design itself is the best possible or not - Is there a problem with this design? For example issues with Android disposing of the activity? Any other issues?

Answer (score 1):

The main risk with building your APIs based on the Activity is that you are basically tying your API to the activity lifecycle, I assume an API like that for messaging should be available on both the main and UI threads. I prefer using  interfaces for designing API's. Dagger is very helpful for creating singletons which can be injected anywhere.

Comment: Let's say the activity is destroyed.. since its the main activity it means the app can't function anyway so maybe I'm correct in assuming it won't matter since the user will restart the application anyway?

Comment: Essentially it is good practice to separate UI from your API. The activity was designed for UI related work. A read up here will help you understand better how to architecture your application  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html